# AWS - Set up FTP on multiple AWS instances

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2

My client's wordpress website is running on AWS two instances. So we have set up two FTPs for two different instances. Whenever I want to upload changes on file level I have to upload on both instances. So is there any way that I can upload my changes only one time and that will affect to both instances?

Answer (score 0):

Aws cloud is also like a normal machines. So you have to machines with 2 different IP. Now you want to push some files into those machines.

If its linux write a script using shell or python fabric or what ever language you are comfortable with.

If its windows you have to search for ftp tools with pushes same files for multiple machines .

This question is not relevant to aws but hopping the above method would solve the issue